# remove Realm default path

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I just updated my RealmSwift framework to 0.97 and the following code is giving me an error saying that type `Realm` has no member `defaultPath`:

```
var error: NSError?
do {
    try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(Realm.defaultPath)
} catch let error1 as NSError {
    error = error1
}
```

I am still in the testing phase, so I need to wipe the Realm persistency clean each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because since Realm 0.95, the property dictating the file path of Realm files was moved directly out of the `Realm` object and moved to a new `Configuration` property object.

As such, to get the file path to the default Realm, you would instead call

```
do {
    try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.path!)
} catch {}
```